# file_put_contents in PHP function doesn't work properly

Tags: php, file

I have this datas:

> SL-40551735,8 SL-40551734,8 75144,5 201761,0 10257,9 40173,97
>   853703,199

and I want it to be written in a .txt file with the file_put_contents function.

The problem is: in the file, the only data that is written is this:

> 75144,5 201761,0 10257,9 40173,97 853703,199

and

> SL-40551735,8 SL-40551734,8

is not written. The syntax is :

```
file_put_contents("stock.txt", implode("\n", $csv));
```

Can you help me to write all data?

Comment: Please provide the correct code. You do an `implode` which requires an array but you've never mentioned that you have any array nor have you told us how that array looks like.

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry for my bad english. Yes, it is a big array that contains datas like i gave in the exemple but only the int variable it is written in txt and and dont' know why

Comment: You still haven't shown how the array looks like. You're only showing the data you claim it might contain.

Answer (score 0):

it is working:

```
<?php
 $csv = ['SL-40551735,8', 'SL-40551734,8', '75144,5', '201761,0', '10257,9', '40173,97', '853703,199'];
 file_put_contents("stock.txt", implode("\n", $csv));
```